# yii2 dropdownlist onchange

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, yii2

I am using GoogleChart API to show the customers' sales graphic.

My graphic show all the results correctly. However I want my graphic to show the interval dates. (For ex. last 1 month or last 3 months)

So I decided to use dropdown list.

If user select (last 1 mount or whatever)

How can I change my sql query?

How can I reach what users choose?

What should I do in onchange method?

Please help me :)

My codes below

```
echo $form->field($model, 'sales_id')->dropDownList(
    [
        '0' => 'All the times',
        '1' => 'This Month',
        '2'=>'Last Two Months'
    ],

    [
        'prompt'=>'Choose the date interval for graphic',

        'onchange'=>''


    ]
);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Your `onchange` attribute should call a JavaScript function that makes an [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp) request to your server with the date-range criteria from the dropdown menu. Your server-side Yii script should then create the query for the sales data, and add a [BETWEEN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm) clause for the date range. The Yii script should then perform the query, and return the results. The JavaScript AJAX function should then handle this response, and print it to the page in the expected presentation format.